# Como detectar se um elemento está acompanhado de algum texto com jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma determinada `div.box` que se repetirá várias vezes, e algumas delas possui um link (`a.link`) com uma classe específica.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="box" data-id="1">
Primeiro texto
</div>

<div class="box" data-id="2">
Segundo texto <a class="link">Clique aqui</a>
</div>

<div class="box" data-id="3">
<a class="link">Clique aqui</a>
</div>

<div class="box" data-id="4">
Testando
</div>
```

Das `divs` apresentadas acima, preciso detectar que, em volta do `a.link`, não exista textos. Ou seja, do exemplo acima poderia retornar apenas a `div.box` cujo o `data-id` é igual a `3`.

Como é que posso detectar isso através do jQuery?

Ou seja, tenho que me certificar que a `div.box` só contenha dentro dela esse elemento `a.link` (e nada mais além disso).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Há várias condições que têm de ser verificadas. A maneira que me parece mais certa é percorrer todos os `childNodes` e verificar quantos há que não estejam vazios. Ao mesmo tempo verificar se pelo menos um deles têm o elemento/classe desejados:

```
function temSoClasse(elInicial, seletor) {
    return = $(elInicial).filter(function () {
        var hasLink = false;
        var nodes = $(this.childNodes).filter(function (i, el) {
            if (el.nodeType == 1) {
                if ($(el).parent().find(seletor).length) hasLink = true;
                return true;
            }
            return el.textContent.trim().length;
        });
        return nodes.length == 1 && hasLink;
    });
}
```

E depois pode usar-se assim:

```
var els = temSoClasse('.box', 'a.link');
els.css('color', 'blue'); // vai mudar a côr do elemento que se procura
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kps5xbec/

---

Uma versão mais comprimida poderia ser assim:

```
function temSoClasse(elInicial, seletor) {
    return $(elInicial).filter(function () {
        return this.querySelector(seletor) && $(this.childNodes).filter(function (i, el) {
            return el.textContent.trim().length;
        }).length == 1;
    });
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kps5xbec/8/

Comment: +1. A ideia da função é maravilhosa. Isso torna o código reutilizável.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters ótimo! Na próxima podes deixar a pergunta aberta mais tempo :P

Comment: É, o @bigown já tinha falando há muito tempo pra eu parar com essa mania. Isso acontece por as vezes achar que não vão ser muitos que vão responder

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu às vezes vejo a pergunta no trabalho e só quando chego a casa tenho tempo de responder... não tens nada a perder :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters nada impede de trocar a aceitação. Aceite a que é melhor.

Comment: Se der uma [melhorada no código](http://jsfiddle.net/kps5xbec/3/), você um [pouco de performance](http://jsfiddle.net/kps5xbec/4/).

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown é verdade que ás vezes faço mais completo para o utilizador perceber os passos. Daria para optimizar mais mas não acho que seja seguro dizer que um é mais rápido que o outro: http://jsfiddle.net/kps5xbec/5/

Comment: Sim, suas respostas são ótimas. Nesse caso o que diferenciou da minha foi ter criado uma função e eu não, no mais ficou na mesma, eu acho. Os dois códigos ficam realmente muito próximos([1](http://jsfiddle.net/kps5xbec/6/) e [2](http://jsfiddle.net/kps5xbec/7/), *[não costumo usar Date pra esses testes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/313893/1267304])*), mas não dá pra negar que `$(el).parent().find(seletor)` pode ser executado fora do segundo `filter()`, pois dentro ele está reduntante.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown tens razão que esse `.find()` pode estar fora do `filter()`. Bem visto. Juntei na resposta uma nova versão.

Answer (score 2):

Acho que achei uma forma:

```
var list = $(".box").filter(function(i, el) 
{
    return Array.from(el.childNodes).filter(function(cn) 
    {
        return  cn.textContent.trim() != "" && 
                cn.nodeType == 3;
    }).length == 0;
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03029x9d/1/)**</kbd>

Explanação:

1. Em cima do seletor `$(".box")` rodamos um [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), já que o intuito é filtrar os elementos que não tenham texto entre o elemento `a`;
2. Para cada elemento, pegamos a coleção [`childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) que contém os elementos de texto que iremos verificar;
3. A `nodeList` não é bem um array, então para poder rodar mais um `filter()` criamos um array com [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), e então rodamos o `filter()`;
4. A condição desse último `filter()` é ele ser do tipo texto(`nodeType == 3`) e não ser vazio(`textContent.trim() != ""`), pois há textNodes apenas com quebra de linha;
5. Esse último `filter()` sendo vazio(`.length == 0`), temos a certeza - assim espero haha - de ele não ter `textNodes` imadiatamente abaixo dele.

**UPDATE**

Bom, se é pra deixar a função reutilizável, dá pra criar um método no jQuery, acho que fica mais correto e dentro do padrão:

```
$.fn.checarElemento = function(checarFilhos)
{
    return $(this).filter(function(i, el) 
    {
        return $(el).find(checarFilhos).length > 0 && Array.from(el.childNodes).filter(function(cn) 
        {
            return  cn.textContent.trim() != "" && 
                    cn.nodeType == 3;
        }).length == 0;
    });
};
```

E pra garantir que haja o seletor deseja dentro do elemento em questão, adicionei a simples condição `$(el).find(checarFilhos).length > 0`, que se não for satisfeita, nem roda o `filter()` sobre o `childNodes`. Micro otimização, talvez? Uso:

```
$(".box").checarElemento("a.link");
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/03029x9d/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: eu tinha pensando numa gambiarra. Dentro do filter: `$(this).html().substr(0, 2) == '<a'`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters cara, as vezes pode funcionar sim, inclusive se você for usar sempre para a mesma estrutura. Da forma que eu fiz pretende funcionar de forma genérica, além de que foi um bom exercício :). Atualizei com explicação.

Comment: Muito bom esse exercício. Me inspirou a dar uma resposta :). A sua resposta me deu uma ideia.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters muito bom. A idéia é aprender e evoluir sempre.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters update ^^

Comment: Que legal! Dá pra fazer com o `find` também! Geralmente eu costumo utilizar o `filter` com uma `closure`. Não sabia que dava pra usar com `find`, isso é bem interessante!

Answer (score 2):

Como disse o @DontVoteMeDown, "... esse é um bom exercício".

```
$(".box").filter(function(i) 
{
    var $that =  $(this);

    var node = $that.contents().get(0);

     if ($that.contents().length == 1 && $(node).is('a')) {
        return true;
     }

     return false;

});
```

Quando utilizamos a função `$.contents`, o jQuery retorna os nodes presentes dentro daquele elemento.

Então, eu verifico se existe apenas um nó com `$(this).contents().length == 1`.

Em seguida verifico se o nó é elemento cuja tag é `a`, através do `$(node).is('a')`.

Através da função `$.is` é que verificamos se o elemento é um link. Como `node` não é um seletor jQuery, é necessário utilizá-lo com o jQuery através do `$(...)`.

O `$(this).contents().get(0)` fica encarregado de pegar o primeiro elemento.

Assim temos a verificação que o `div.box` possui um nó, e se esse nó é um link.

**Atualização**: Seguindo o exemplo da resposta do @DontVoteMeDown, poderíamos também, ao invés de utilizar `$(node).is('a')`, fazer da seguinte forma:

```
 if ($that.contents().length == 1 && node.nodeType == 3) {
     return true;
 }
```